# How to get access to package routes

Tags: php, laravel, package

i've created a package, as descriped in laravel docs.

Then i created the routes.php and add a simple route

```
Route::get('package', function() {
   echo "It works!";
});
```

It throws the exception

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException
```

Then i run

```
 php composer.phar dump-autoload
```

via console, but still this exception.

As descriped in other threads, i should register the service provider to app.php. So i added it

```
'Vendor\Package\PackageServiceProvider'
```

Now it throws the exception, that service class does not exists.

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException
```

What did I miss?

**Edit**

If i add the route to apps routes.php it works.

Answer (score 1):

I think your service provider class defined in global namespace. Do you define namespace of service provider class like:

```
namespace Vendor\Package\PackageServiceProvider;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class PackageServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    // implement your service provider interface
    // you should include your route.php in the boot method of your service provider

    function boot() {
        include __DIR__.'/../../routes.php';
    }
}
```

Comment: I've created the package, as described in docs (php artisan workbench vendor/package --resources) and include the route.php like above. 

the routes.php should be located in src-folder of package, right?

Comment: in one level up. Because routes it's not source of your package it's just configurations.